# How to create optimised and progressive Images (JPG, PNG) in Go lang

Tags: go, imagemagick, imagick, go-imagick

I am using the following code in Go to resize my images in JPEG and PNG format. So, how do I convert them to progressive and optimized using [Imagick](https://github.com/gographics/imagick). I'm using `ImageMagick 6.9.3-8 Q16 x86_64` on `ubuntu 14.04`

I am saying optimized reason being I used the following command to test whether image size gets reduced or not. But, it increases the output file size.

**Command :**

```
convert -strip -interlace Plane input-file.jpg output-file.jpg
```

**Go code :**

```
        size = fmt.Sprintf("%dx%d^+0+0", w, h)
        tx := mw.TransformImage("", size)
        tx.SetImageGravity(imagick.GRAVITY_CENTER)
        offsetX := -(int(w) - int(tx.GetImageWidth())) / 2
        offsetY := -(int(h) - int(tx.GetImageHeight())) / 2
        err := tx.ExtentImage(w, h, offsetX, offsetY)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your **convert** command line strips the image and gives it a planar interlace scheme. An equivalent Go code should call mw.StripImage() and mw.SetImageInterlaceScheme(INTERLACE_PLANE).

[edit] Are you trying to follow [this example](https://coderwall.com/p/ryzmaa/use-imagemagick-to-create-optimised-and-progressive-jpgs) ? If so, -interlace Plane is responsible for making the image progressive, but this doesn’t make it any smaller. The part that does that is -quality 80, which you can implement in Go by calling mw.SetImageCompressionQuality(80).

Comment: I did that but it does it make the images to be progressive by just setting the Interlacescheme to be `INTERLACE_PLANE`?

Comment: Yes, but this has nothing to do with size (see edit).

Comment: Yes, my primary goal was to create the image to be progressive and i was trying to follow the same example. So, I didn't use CompressionQuality as mentioned in the example. So, my doubt was why it increased the size compared to original image

Comment: Making an image progressive can result in a smaller file, or in a bigger one. There is no rule.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So, doing the same would work for rest of the image format also. Is it correct? Why i am asking is because. I couldn't understand why does rest of the interlace means here `https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/gographics/imagick.v3/imagick#InterlaceType` i.e. `JPEGInterlace` or `pngInterlace`

Comment: I tested the code after setting `ImageInterlaceScheme` to be `plane`. But in the browser, it still doesn't show in progressive manner after throttling the bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ResizeImage` instead

```
tx.ResizeImage(w, h, imagick.FILTER_LANCZOS, 1)
```

See the [resizing example](https://github.com/gographics/imagick/blob/master/examples/resize/main.go#L33)

Comment: I need to crop the image evenly from both the corners. That's why I am using as mentioned above

Comment: Right but your new image is the same size as the original why would it be a different size?